# How to convert a input(string) to date in Java?

Tags: java, string, input, time

I'm new to Java, I'm getting an exception when I try to convert string to simple date format.

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");

System.out.print("Time period (DD/MM/YYYY): ");
String sTime = input.nextLine();

Date time = dateFormat.parse(sTime);
```

Comment: What's the exception? And what's the input?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica It's a `java.text.ParseException` and String is a simple user input like `05/08/2020`.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: If you are getting an exception, please pate the full stack trace into your question, formatted as code for readability. And thanks for the further information. Please put that in your question too so we have everything in one place. Surprisingly many users don’t read the comments.

Comment: Also, while your code example is short, which is nice, I recommend that you shorten it further by leaving out the scanner and hardcoding the input into your code. or as suggested on [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) “If the code performs I/O to files, replace the file I/O with dummy data structures in problems that are unrelated to input/output.” Your problem is unrelated to user input.

Answer (score 0):

The **parse()** method of **DateFormat** throws **ParseException**. Also the format has `mm` which shows minutes value in Date. `MM` shows the months value which is what you want.

```html
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        
        System.out.print("Time period (DD/MM/YYYY): ");
        String sTime = input.nextLine();
        
        Date time = dateFormat.parse(sTime);
```

Comment: parse method of DateFormat throws ParseException. Also the format has "mm" which shows minutes value in Date. MM shows the months value

Answer (score 0):

The parse method of DateFormat throws ParseException.
So change the main to

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws ParseException
```

also include the following

```
import java.text.ParseException;
```